# Terraform: S3 bucket for website redirect: issue with "website_endpoint"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to use Terraform to create an S3 bucket for a redirect to another S3 bucket hosting a static website....

Current setting:

- main s3 bucket name: myDomain.com
- redirect s3 bucket name: [www.myDomain.com](http://www.myDomain.com)

the challenge is when I create a CloudFront distribution and in the "origin" parameters I cannot get them right...

my provider settings:

```
terraform {
   required_providers {
      aws = {
         source = "hashicorp/aws"
         version = "~>4.0"
      }
   }
}
```

my code:

```
origin {
   domain_name = aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration.www_website.website_endpoint
   origin_id = aws_s3_bucket.www_bucket.id
}
```

because

> aws_s3_bucket.www_bucket_website_endpoint

is deprecated, I only can use

> aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration.www_website.website_endpoint

but I get the following error: `The parameter Origin DomainName does not refer to a valid s3 bucket`

this seems to be a known issue/bug as per this post: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/aws-cloudfront-origin-originname-bug/37997

I have thought of a couple of "fixes":

1. run the code with a placeholder Origin DomainName (aws_s3_bucket.www_bucket.bucket_regional_domain_name) and then do a manual adjustment every time I run the code
2. downgrade the provider version till aws_s3_bucket.www_bucket_website_endpoint was not deprecated (I think at 3.0) --> but this result in many features not available and rework half of my code

if you were me, how would you fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: If you've got a CloudFront distribution, why are you using an S3 bucket to do the redirect?

Comment: What would be the alternative? How can I redirect the www trafic to the non-www s3 bucket website?

Comment: The example from the documentation says the bucket regional endpoint name can be used, i.e., `aws_s3_bucket.www_bucket.bucket_regional_domain_name`. Additionally, the `origin_id` does not have to be an S3 bucket ID, which in your example would be the bucket name since you are using the ID attribute (`aws_s3_bucket.www_bucket.id`).

Comment: thank you @Marko, but the official AWS documentation says clearly that it must be the "website url" -- Amazon S3 bucket configured as a website – DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET.s3-website.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using the `custom_origin_config` property in the CloudFront distribution and in particular:

```
    Resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "www_cf_dist" {
      provider            = aws.Milan
      enabled             = true
      aliases             = [var.www_domain_name]
      origin {
        origin_id   = aws_s3_bucket.www_bucket.id
        domain_name = aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration.www_website.website_endpoint
        `custom_origin_config` {
          origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"
          http_port  = "80"
          https_port = "443"
          origin_ssl_protocols = ["TLSv1.2"]
        }
      }
      default_cache_behavior {
...
```

this fixed the issue!